# ActiveRecord: group by relation attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models:

```
Characteristic
  name

Value 
 characteristic_id
 name
```

and Value `belongs_to` Characteristic, Characteristic `has_many` Values

I'd like to have a query returning characteristics'names as keys and as values, the names of the associated values to this characteristic:

```
{characteristic_1_name: [value_associated_1.name, value_associated_2.name], characteristic_2_name: [value_associated_3.name, value_associated_4.name]}
```

I tried many queries using joins, select, but couldn't make this work.

How could I get this result without using ruby's methods (map etc which are slow).

any input will be much appreciated

Comment: Look up arel_table, I don't think this is achievable with activerecord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use postgresql

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    WITH characteristics_arr AS
      (SELECT characteristics.name AS name,
              array_agg(
                        values.id) AS arr
       FROM CHARACTERISTICS
       INNER JOIN
       VALUES ON characteristics.id =
       VALUES.characteristic_id
       GROUP BY characteristics.name)
    SELECT json_object_agg(name, arr)
    FROM characteristics_arr
)
```